# metaclass conflict upon dynamically creating classes with type (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.9

The aim of the following code is to dynamically create a class based on the user's input.

```
class BaseClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.placeholder = ""


if __name__ == '__main__':
    className = input("Please enter the name of new class: ")
    baseClass = input("Please enter name of base class: ")
    try:
        newClass = type(className, tuple(baseClass), {})
        print(f"Class {newClass} Created")
    except TypeError as e:
        print(e)
```

However, upon entering the input:

```
NewClass
BaseClass
```

I receive the follwing exception:

> metaclass conflict: the metaclass of a derived class must be a
> (non-strict) subclass of the metaclasses of all its bases

Why the program doesn't recognized the class `BaseClass`? What would be the proper use of the `type` function?

Note: I'm running python v3.9.6.

Example program output snippet:
[image]

Comment: `baseClass` is a string not a reference to the actual class itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bases have to be classes not strings, so you need to get the class from string name:

```
class BaseClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.placeholder = ""


if __name__ == '__main__':
    #className = input("Please enter the name of new class: ")
    #baseClass = input("Please enter name of base class: ")

    className = 'Foo'
    baseClass = 'BaseClass'

    baseClassObj = globals().get(baseClass, None)
    if baseClassObj:
        newClass = type(className, (baseClassObj, ), dict())
        print(f"Class {newClass} Created")
    else:
        print('baseClass not found!')
```

Out:

```
Class <class '__main__.Foo'> Created
```